# Sphinx using postgreSQL and Rails on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, sphinx

I have been trying to figure this out for the past day and figure it is an easy question for those who know Sphinx.  I have Sphinx installed at /Users/gabemcmillan/src/sphinx-0.9.9/ and in my sphinx.yml file I have the entry below, which is what another post said to do, but I don't think its the right bin path.  I am confused which bin path to point to.  I checked the spinx-0.9.9 directory and dont see a bin path, so I don't know where to point to.

sphinx.yml file:

development:
    bin_path: '/usr/local/bin'

Error I get when trying to run: rake thinking_sphinx:index

Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name

For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html
Generating Configuration to /Users/gabemcmillan/rails_projects/pa1/config/development.sphinx.conf
sh: /usr/local/bin/indexer: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you have installed sphinx at /Users/gabemcmillan/src/sphinx-0.9.9 I get the feeling you mean you unpacked it there. You still need to build and install it. Look in /Users/gabemcmillan/src/sphinx-0.9.9doc/sphinx.html for instructions. BTW you will probably need to install the Developer tools which you can get from your snow-leopard installation disk.

Comment: Hi Eelke, I followed the instructions from this post:  http://mediumexposure.com/installing-sphinx-postgres-leopard-or-ubuntu/  and did, is there another step in addition to that?:   ~% curl -O http://www.sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-0.9.8.1.tar.gz
  ~% tar xzf sphinx-0.9.8.1.tar.gz
  ~% cd sphinx-0.9.8.1
  ~% export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib" 
  ~% ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pgsql --without-mysql
  ~% make
  ~% sudo make install

Comment: Then it has been installed under /usr/local (--prefix option). So /usr/local/bin is the right path. You should be able to find indexer and searchd in that path. If it isn't there you can try to locate it with the following command: find / -name searchd

Comment: I finally reinstalled postgreSQL and Sphinx via Homebrew and pointed to the new locations.  It works now.  Wish I would have started with Homebrew first, would have saved 2 days.